# Locus of intersection of lines.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

We have a line which touches $x$ axis at $A=(7,0)$ and $B=(0,-5)$. A variable line PQ which touches $x$ axis at P and $y$ axis at Q is perpendicular to the line $AB$. Now we have to find the locus of R which is the point of intersection of $AQ$ and $BP$.

Now first of all equation of AB can be written as $$AB:5x-7y=35$$
Taking $P=(p,0) $ and $Q=(0,q)$

Equation of $PQ$  can be written as $$PQ: qx+py=qp$$

Since PQ is perpendicular to AB using 
$$slope(PQ) \cdot slope (AB)=-1$$
$$\Rightarrow 5q=7p \tag1$$

Now writing the equation of $AQ$ using $(7,0)$ and $(0,q)$
$$AQ: qx+7y-7q=0$$

Similarly writing the equation of $BP$ using $(0,-5)$ and $(p,0)$
$$BP: 5x-py-5p=0$$

Now since $R = (h,k)$ is the intersection of $AQ$ and $BP$ solving the two equations we get

$$h=\dfrac{35p+7pq}{35+pq} \tag2$$ 
$$k=\dfrac{35q-5pq}{35+pq} \tag3$$

I just don't know how can I go ahead and use equation $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$ in order to relate the terms to get the locus.

Please help me further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you divide the equations, you get $$\frac hk=\frac{35p+7pq}{35q-5pq}$$

Now substitute $$q=\frac{7p}{5}$$ into this and simplify so $$\frac hk=\frac{25+7p}{35-5p}$$

Now rearrange this to get $$p=\frac{35h-25k}{7k+5h}$$ and substitute this into the equation of the line $BP$ which is $5h-pk-5p=0$, and after some simplification you end up with $$h^2+k^2-7h+5k=0$$

Which basically gives you the locus of a circle.
$$(h-\frac{7}{2})^2+(k+\frac{5}{2})^2=\frac{74}{4}$$

Note that this circle has a centre which is the midpoint of $AB$, and passes through $A$, $B$ and the origin $O$.

Comment: Thanks@jyotishraj-thoudam for your suggested edit.

Answer (score 2):

Into the equations for *h* and *k* substitute *p* for *q*: $q=\frac75p$ and
$$h=\frac{35p+\frac{49}5p^2}{35+\frac75p^2}$$
$$k=\frac{49p-7p^2}{35+\frac75p^2}$$
This is a parametric equation in *p*. If we convert this to an implicit function and remove *p* (I did this in Wolfram Alpha) we get:
$$\frac{-777323750h+111046250 h^2+555231250k+111046250 k^2}{625}=0$$
$$h^2-7h+k^2+5k=0$$
$$(h-\tfrac72)^2+(k+\tfrac52)^2=\tfrac{37}2$$
which, of course, is a circle centred on $(\frac72,-\frac52)$ with radius $\sqrt{\frac{37}2}$.

Comment: Which terms, and where?

Comment: I plugged my implicit equation and the original parametric into Wolfram Alpha, and got the same ellipse. You may have pushed your pencil wrongly with the simplification.

Comment: I have also checked your parametric pair on WA and I get my answer, not yours, so there must be a mistake in what you have input.

Comment: As a quick check, whatever answer is correct must be a curve passing through the origin (when $P$ and $Q$ coincide with the origin) and yoirs does not

Comment: Do wait for a while. The problem is in my resultant computation (not simplifying the expressions for h/k) but I'm outside now and haven't much time for calculations.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Have corrected the resultant calculation. Same results as above.

Answer (score 1):

We note that $P$ is an orthocenter of the triangle $ABQ$. So $\angle BRQ = 90^{\circ}$ and thus $R$ describes a circle with diameter $AB=\sqrt{74}$. So the locus of point $R(x,y)$ is $$(x-{7\over 2})^2+(y+{5\over 2})^2 = {74\over 4}$$